# Function call inside assert == bad?

Tags: c, coding-style, assert

I have just dug up a bug in some code we're working with* that was failing due to the following situation:

```
Assert(SomeVitalFunction(foo) == OK)
```

This worked fine all the time the DEBUG macros were #defined:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
    #define Assert(x)  if((x) == 0){/*some error handling*/}
#else
    #define Assert(x)
#endif
```

But when we `#undef'd DEBUG` it has the effect of deleting the vital function call from the code.

I can't for the life of me work out how that could ever work with DEBUG `#undef`'d, and it seems a bad idea generally to put any sort of function call inside an assert like this.

Have I missed something?

* = *Edit to clarify following Carpetsmoker's comment:* The code comes from a particularly backward cabal of Elbonian code slaves, our task has been to hack, slash, shave, polish, sanitize and apply lipstick to the thing.

Comment: The point of `assert` is to "*help programmers find bugs in their programs*" ... So all aserts should ideally be removable, and everything should still work the same. So you are right in your observation, and you or one of your coworkers made a mistake in the past.

Comment: I wrote a Visual Studio macro long ago to look through the codebase for this (in those days, looking for `ASSERT(...(...)` - i.e. 2 or more opening brackets before the closing one) because it is such a huge problem when it happens.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have missed nothing.

Asserts should always be written as if they could disappear at the flick of a compiler switch.

You *can* call functions that take a relatively long time to complete inside an assert (for example analysing the integrity of a data structure), because the function call will not be present in the release build. The flip side of this is that you *cannot* call functions that are necessary for correct operation.

Answer (score 2):

It depends upon what `SomeVitalFunction` is doing. If it has no *interesting* side-effects, it is ok to use it inside an `assert`. But if calling or not calling `SomeVitalFunction` is essential to the program, it is a bug.

For instance, on POSIX, [kill(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html) with a 0 signal is only useful to test if a process is living. I would imagine that you might be sometimes tempted to use

```
 assert(kill(sompid, 0) == 0); // process sompid exists
```

assuming that you always suppose that the process `sompid` is still running.

Likewise, you might use `assert(hash_table_count(htbl)>0);` to check that some hash table `htbl` is not empty.

BTW, notice that [assert(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/assert.3.html) is *documented* as being ignored if you compile with `-DNDEBUG` preprocessor option (not if `-DDEBUG` is not given).